# How to select an object that returns twice in a json list that comes from an api request?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a code that will return Shabbat times.
I was able to print the title and date from the list but got stuck when I wanted to return the candle lighting times, since this is inside the "title" object that is more than once on this json list.
A URL for example - https://www.hebcal.com/shabbat/?cfg=json&geonameid=293397

I tried to play with class, thanks to another question asked here which is somehow similar to that but I could not finally arrange it to succeed.

```py
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

geonameid_list = {
    "jerusalem": "281184",
    "tel aviv": "293397",
    "petach tikvah": "293918",
    "be'er sheva": "295530",
    "ashdod": "295629"
}


def geoname(message, geo):
    while True:
        userinput = (input(message))
        if userinput in list(geo.values()):
            return userinput
        else:
            print("Not in the list! Please try again.")


user_input = geoname("Please enter one of the cities " + str(list(geonameid_list.values())) + ": ",
                     geonameid_list)

data = {
    "geonameid": user_input,
    "m": "50",
    "b": "18"
}

url = requests.get("https://www.hebcal.com/shabbat/?cfg=json", params=data)


class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pList = []

    def addPerson(self, title, candle):
        self.pList.append(Person(self, title))


class Person:
    def __init__(self, title, candle):
        self.nom = title
        self.num = candle


a = Example()
a.addPerson('title', 'candles')

while True:
    try:
        url.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError as http_error:
        print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_error}')
    except Exception as error:
        print(f'Other error occurred: {error}')
    else:
        user_input = user_input
        response_url = url.json()
        print(response_url["title"])
        print(response_url["date"])
        print(response_url["items"])
        for person in a.pList:
            if person.num == 'candles':
                break
            else:
                print("Not found.")
        break
```

The option:

```py
print(response_url["items"])
```

Returns all the items from the list. it does not connected to anything... It's just an attempt I made.

Comment: i'm not sure if i understand what is wrong about `response_url["items"]`. can you add expected vs. actual behavior to your question?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. I just wanted to let you know that I know it is not connected to anything ^^"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need to return the candle lighting times from the json response right. Then try this,
In else statement apply this,

```
else:
    user_input = user_input
    response_url = url.json()
    for lighting_times in response_url['items']:
        if lighting_times['category'] == 'candles':
            print(lighting_times['title'])
    # print(response_url["title"])
    # print(response_url["date"])
    # print(response_url["items"])
```

Answer (score 2):

`for lighting_times in response_url['items']:` give an TypeError like this `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable`

Actually, I'd first suggest that you use functions to separate your code and launch it as a script (you don't have to use class) :

```py
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    main()
```

but this is completely up to you :)

Then, to access the returned data from this API, you'll have to encode the `response_url.text` which is the JSON you can see from the url you gave in example.

Try something like this :

```py
import requests
import json # don't forget to import json ;)
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

def main():
    geonameid_list = {
        "jerusalem": "281184",
        "tel aviv": "293397",
        "petach tikvah": "293918",
        "be'er sheva": "295530",
        "ashdod": "295629"
    }

    user_input = geoname("Please enter one of the cities " + str(list(geonameid_list.values())) + ": ",
                         geonameid_list)

    data = {
        "geonameid": user_input,
        "m": "50",
        "b": "18"
    }

    url = requests.get("https://www.hebcal.com/shabbat/?cfg=json", params=data)
    my_json = url.text # this is unicode !! you have to encode it like bellow
    my_encoded_json = my_json.encode('utf-8') # now you have a string 

    # print(type(my_json.encode('utf-8')))
    my_object = json.loads(my_encoded_json)

    print(type(my_encoded_json)) # should be a string
    print(type(my_object)) # should be a dict

    for item in my_object.items:
        print(item) # should rails TypeError not iterable

def geoname(message, geo):
    while True:
        userinput = (input(message))
        if userinput in list(geo.values()):
            return userinput
        else:
            print("Not in the list! Please try again.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I'd also recommend not to force the user input to be like integers, it's very more user friendly to do so : `user_input = geoname("Please enter one of the cities " + str(list(geonameid_list.keys())) + ": ",
                         geonameid_list)`

Comment: I'd have done the same, but I think this decision does not belong to us @lucyjosef ;)

Comment: I wanted to take care of this later because the url is taken from the user input... and if I put the keys instead of the values - it will return an error.

Comment: I took your suggestions and put them in my code. Thanks a lot! @leonardgrand